# Как в Userscpirt для Tampermonkey сделать имитацию клика мышкой через JQuery?

Tags: jquery

[image: Вид товара]

Я пишу userscript в Tampermonkey для сайта Avito.ru.
Его задача - при открытии страницы добавления товара скрипт автоматически выбирает категорию и вид товара. Текущее состояние кода:
`
$(document).ready(function(){

```
//Бытовая электроника -> Товары для компьютера
$('input[value="101"]').next().click();   

//Аксессуары
$('select[name="params[483]"] option:eq(11)').attr('selected', 'selected');});`
```

Суть проблемы: категория и подкатегория выбирается, но выпадающий список с видом товара не отображается. Если нажать "Продолжить", то выскочит ошибка и выпадающий список появится, вторая часть кода в скрипте сработает.

Как я понимаю - он подгружается динамически при клике мышкой по категории, но почему то отказывается подгружаться при клике через JQuery. Использую JQuery потому что мне так удобнее.

Даже если делать .click() на всех трёх элементах - вид не подгружается. Смотрите картинку.[image: дерево input-а]

Вопрос: как решить данную задачу? Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт сам выбирал вид товара сразу?

Comment: не на тот элемент нажимаете =) вот список и не появляется =),
ну а если нужно точнее, то нужно ссылку на данный список

Comment: Если нажимать на label или на input - категория не выбирается.

Comment: ссылку на данный список дайте

Comment: https://www.avito.ru/additem

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ на свою задачу. Проблема была в том, что подключал JQuery второй раз, а на Авито он уже есть, хотя в исходниках не видно подключения. Возникал конфликт.

```
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
```

После удаления этой строки всё заработало как нужно.
Всех благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы избежать конфликта версий, нужно почитать про это:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Comment: Даже в таком виде два jQuery взаимодействуют так себе.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com